# If with OR AND vs multiple If

Tags: java, performance

Generally we prefer using

```
if(a==b || c==d)
```

in our code. I have got to a situation where i need to provider user with some details about what exactly went wrong. So i have broken this to

```
 if(a!=b) {
    doX();
    } 
    if(c!=d) {
    doY();
    }
```

What are the performance impact of this change from java perspective ?

Comment: What have you measured them to be? I assuyme your `f` is meant to be `else if`, and that you'd normally have an `else` clause at the end with the normal code? Do you have any evidence that this trivial change is causing a problem? Is it in a particularly-frequently-called (e.g. in a tight loop) piece of code?

Comment: The main difference is, that c and d will be evaluated, while they might not be in the first form. Aside from that, there will be no measurable impact.

Comment: This may seem like an intelligent question but it's not. If you are serious about performance, you're looking in the wrong place. No application gains performance by optimizing `if` blocks. They gain it by multi-threading, or connection pooling or caching etc.. i.e. big steps that have an impact overall.

Answer (score 3):

It *depends on the compiler* (and *optimizer*), however, the *1st choice* could be slighly better:

```
  (a == b) || (c == d)
```

could be executed as one integer arithmetic formula (`false == 0, true != 0`)

```
  (a == b) + (c == d)
```

and then checked if the `result > 0`. So there's only one condition check and *one* potential Branch Prediction failure that costs. To *make* compiler doing this way, re-write your code into

```
   if ((a == b) | (c == d)) { // Note | instead of ||
     ...
   }
```

In the 2nd fragment

```
  if (a != b) {
    if (c != d) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

there're *two* conditions check and *two* potential Branch Prediction failures.
The figures (which *vary* from CPU to CPU) are

```
  comparison = 1/3..1 ticks
  addition   = 1/3..1 ticks
  if         = 1..20  ticks (20 if prediction appeared to be wrong)
```

In any case the gain is symbolic and unless you have to execute your code within deep loops (in that case you may prefer rewrite and aggressively optimize the routine in C) you can use either fragment you like.